# Google Reverse Geocoding - how to choose between a street_address or route?

Tags: reverse-geocoding

I have been using Google's reverse geocoding APIs in a vehicle tracking application to convert lat/lon information into an "address" for at least 5 years.  Recently, this conversion has started yielding some surprising results.

For example, the lat/lon pair, 36.7653111,-121.74852, when plugged into Google Maps, yields "CA-156, Castroville, CA 95012" as the address. This is the desirable answer.

The tracking application yields "11298 Haight St, Castroville, Monterey County, CA, 95012, US"  The problem is that the JSON result contains two "street_address" and one "route" type. The dumb algorithm of choosing the first street_address or route occurring in the result no longer works.  The question now is how to decide which of the possibilities is a better match to the given lan/lon?  The lat/lon is clearly on route CA-156. Haight St. does not cross CA-156 at all.

What is special about this case is that the vehicle is not travelling on either of the streets in the two "street_address" types but is on the street in the route. In this case,  the route should have been given priority over the two street_address types.

I have now examined the results of hundreds of reverse geocodings.  There does not appear to be any simple algorithmic way of choosing the best result. For example, reverse geocoding 37.31674,-122.0472125 returns only two results:

```
Type: premise 
Address: Child Development Center, Cupertino, Santa Clara County, CA 95014, US
location_type: ROOFTOP
37.316425,-122.0460558 Distance: 354.7286202778164 Feet

Type: route 
Address: CA-85, Cupertino, Santa Clara County, CA 95014, US
location_type: GEOMETRIC_CENTER
37.3145586,-122.0461306 Distance: 855.4738140974437 Feet
```

The vehicle is travelling on CA-85.  Choosing the first result (premise) or the result with least distance, does not yield the best result.

The fundamental problem here is the for "route" types, the distance to the GEOMETRIC_CENTER does not tell you if you are "on the route" (0 distance) or if you are "off the route", how far off.

I have filed a case with Google.  If I get a useful response, I will post it here.

Comment: Not sure why this question has been downvoted.  This is a very valid reasonable question. Am having the same problem.  When google gives two competing addresses - one on freeway and one on side street, what is the best way to choose one of these addresses?

Answer (score 1):

If you are reverse geocoding lat/lon information coming from in-vehicle devices here are two approached that significantly improve the results.  The discussion assumes you have limited the results to types:  "premise", "street_address" or "route",  If you are interested in other types, you may have to experiment a bit.

First, if the in-vehicle device returns the speed along with lat/lon, then choose the "route" result, if one is present, when the speed is above a certain threshold. Otherwise, choose the "street_address" or "premise" with the least distance to the lat/lon.  You may have to experiment a bit with the speed threshold to find a reasonable value.  For me, 25 MPH seemed to do a decent job.

Second, if you don't have speed or another indication that the vehicle is stopped or moving, then try the following "hack".

Scan the results up to the first occurrence of a "route" and determine amongst "premise" or "street_address" types the one with the least distance to the lat/lon. Remember the "route", if one is found.

Then 
1. If no "route" result exists, return the "premise" or "street_address" with the least distance to the lat/lon.
2. Else 
a. If the "route" has a "route" name that matches the regex "[A-Z]+-[0-9]+", return the route as the best result.
b. Else if a least distance "premise" or "street_address" exists, return that as the best result.
c. Otherwise, return the "route" as a best result.

This is far from perfect, but seems to work well enough for the US which is all I care about right now.  As route names differ significantly from country to country some enhancement will likely be necessary.